# Python ImportError: cannot import name 'Poller' while running pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have referred to [this](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c) tut to get started with pyspark on windows. These are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded spark prebuilt for hadoop 2.7 from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)
2. Extracted spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz to the directory set as `%SPARK_HOME%` in environment variables
3. Downloaded winutils.exe from [here](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)
4. Pasted winutils.exe in `%SPARK_HOME%\bin`
5. Set `%HADOOP_HOME%` to same directory as `%SPARK_HOME%`
6. Set `%PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON%` to ipython
7. Set `%PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS%` to notebook
8. Added `;%SPARK_HOME%\bin` to `%PATH%`
9. But when I run

   ```
   > pyspark --master local[2]
   ```

   I get following error:

   ```
     [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
   [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
       "__main__", mod_spec)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
       exec(code, run_globals)
     File "D:\mahesh\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\Scripts\ipython.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 125, in start_ipython
       return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
       app.initialize(argv)
     File "<decorator-gen-113>", line 2, in initialize
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 308, in initialize
       super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
     File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 450, in initialize
       self.parse_command_line(argv)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 303, in parse_command_line
       return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
     File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 514, in parse_command_line
       return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 243, in initialize_subcommand
       return super(BaseIPythonApplication, self).initialize_subcommand(subc, argv)
     File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 445, in initialize_subcommand
       subapp = import_item(subapp)
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
       module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 31, in <module>
       from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
       from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
     File "d:\mahesh\softwares\python\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.4qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 21, in <module>
       from zmq import (
   ImportError: cannot import name 'Poller'
   ```

I am correctly able to run spark scala shell with `>spark-shell` command.

As you can see in the stack trace, I had win-python installed already at path

```
D:\mahesh\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64
```

Thus, my `%PYTHON_HOME%` is `D:\mahesh\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5`.
But my `%SPARK_HOME%` is `D:\mahesh\Programs\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7`.
Running `where pyspark` command gives following output:

```
D:\mahesh\Programs\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\pyspark
D:\mahesh\Programs\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\pyspark.cmd
D:\mahesh\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\Scripts\pyspark
D:\mahesh\Softwares\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\Scripts\pyspark.cmd
```

I believe my issue is some missconfiguration of my windows spark environment. Thats why I gave all above information. So whats going wrong here?

Note that I performed the steps without using Anaconda and GOW (Gnu on windows) as suggested in the tut.

Comment: I had `WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5` installed. I uninstalled it. Installed `python-3.6.3-amd64`. And then installed `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7`. It started working.

Answer (score 0):

Point your `%PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON%` to a virtual environment with all dependencies including `'Poller'` and then check.
Else you can try installing `'Poller'` in ipython environment( which I frankly dont know how!)

Comment: didnt get what you meant by "virtual environment with all dependencies including". More explanation?

Comment: In python, we create a virtual environment to segregate dependencies of one project from another.   http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/